# Nativescript Images from protected api

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an object "order" with a property that is an array of images urls.
I've tried to create a list of  tags with his source to this urls but the problem is these urls are behind an api server and I'm unable to access directly from  tag. I'm not sure why I'm receiving a FileNotFoundException and not a Forbidden, but it doesn't matter for this issue.

All my normal requests to this api server are done with the option "withCredentials: true", the api use cookies for authentication.

There aren't an api resource to download the image, the access is directly to url. For example if I open the url with my browser (without login in web app) I received a forbidden error, but if I login to my app in browser and paste the image url, the image load correctly.

I'm working with Nativescript angular.

Any idea how could show this list of images?

**UPDATE:**

Following this issue and understanding that src property of Image tag does not send cookies to server, I've created an API end point to received the images like a normal API call.

This is my angular service:

```
public async getPhoto(orderId: number, photoName: string) {
    return await nsHttp.getImage(this.config.API_URL + `/api/tablet/photos/${orderId}/${photoName}`);
}
```

This is the code where I load all data:

```
async loadData(id: number, fromSketch: boolean = false) {
        this.order = await this.orderService.getOrderById(id);

        for (let index = 0; index < this.order.photoNames.length; index++) {
            this.imgTemp = await this.orderService.getPhoto(this.order.orderId, this.order.photoNames[index].photoName);
            this.imagesJPG.push(this.imgTemp);
        }
        console.log('IMAGES: ', this.imagesJPG);
}
```

And this is the presentation code:

```
<ScrollView orientation="vertical" [visibility]="selectedPageItemIndex === 2 ? 'visible' : 'collapse'">
        <StackLayout>
            <CardView margin="10" elevation="5" radius="1" *ngFor="let photo of imagePhotos; let i = index">
                <Image [src]="imagesJPG[i]"></Image>
            </CardView>
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I try to show only one image, for example imagesJPG[0] the image is displayed correctly, but in a ngFor loop no images, no cardview, and no errors appear in console.

I'm not sure if this is the best code to received an array of images and show them, if you have any suggestion I could be very grateful.

Regards

Comment: The same way you are making the authorization request via the browser. Just pass the authorization parameters/tokens (in the HTTP request) in the requested form.

Comment: Hi Nick, in browser, after authentication, all requests agains the server are authenticated, including file download, but in NS <Image src="https://xxxxxxx"> are not. I can't access the url because no cookie is sent to server. In a regular Angular application it's works fine with <img src="xxxxx"> because the browser has the cookie received after authentication.

Comment: NS app doesn't run inside a browser / webview instead it's a native app so you will have to pass your authentication data in headers. Cookies are nothing but special headers sent by default in browser environment, so you just have to make sure you manually write the auth header in your http request to the image from app.

Comment: I've updated code but I continue with a problem.